# Modificar no xml em vários arquivos

Tags: xml, regex, arquivo, text, xml-namespaces

Olá,

Pessoal preciso modificar um valor dentro de um node xml, o problema é que preciso fazer isso em 1300 arquivos de uma vez só, o valor que procuro dentro do nó pode ser qualquer um, não faz diferença o valor que esta lá, só preciso modificar esse nó em todos os arquivos de uma vez só, exemplo:

```
Em um xml pode estar
    <VDesc>9.32</vDesc>
Em outro
    <VDesc>1.45</vDesc>

Em assim por diante.

Preciso modificar em todos arquivos para
    <VDesc>0.00</vDesc>
```

Só isso, alguma sugestão, que ferramenta usar?

Comment: `<VDesc>` aparece mais de uma vez no arquivo ou apenas na linha que deve ser alterado?

Comment: A ferramenta que vai importar esses arquivos é própria ou de terceiros?

Comment: é para ser assim mesmo, `<VDesc>` e `</vDesc>`, **V** e **v**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

baseado em todas as respostas eu consegui resolver o problema de uma maneira simples e muito eficaz, fiz o seguinte:

**Com o Notepad ++**

Opção: "***Localizar***->***Substituir***, Aba ***Localizar em arquivos***", no campo ***Localizar*** coloquei:

```
<vICMSDeson>(\s*\d+\.\d+\s*)<\/vICMSDeson>
```

, e no campo ***Substituir por***, coloquei:

```
<vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
```

, em ***Filtros*** coloquei: *.xml pra buscar somente em arquivos xml, então em  ***Pasta*** eu indiquei o caminho dos arquivos xml, em ***Modo de busca*** selecionei "Expressão regular". Perfeito.

Talvez seja útil para mais alguém.

Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

Se puderes usar perl, ai vai uma sugestão:

```
perl -i -pe 's!<VDesc>.*?</VDesc>!<VDesc>0.00</VDesc>!s' *.xml
```

Se preferires criar um backup do original (a.xml , a.xml.bak):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's!<VDesc>.*?</VDesc>!<VDesc>0.00</VDesc>!s' *.xml
```

(presumi que  os V, v seja V)